# python JupyterNotebook with pandas matrix()

Tags: numpy, sklearn-pandas

Hi there this is my code:

When I try to run this I get an error.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='|', encoding='latin-1')

arreglox = df[df.columns['id':'date_in':'date_out':'objetive':'comments']].as_matrix()

arregloy = df[df.columns[1]].as_matrix()
```

Here is the error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-30-6060fe26b2b1>", line 1
    arreglox = df[df.columns['id':'date_in':'date_out':'objetive':'comments']].as_matrix()
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help me, thank u very much

Comment: It apparently has invalid syntax in a column that you are trying to fetch

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, if you want those columns in that order try this:

```
arreglox = df[['id','date_in','date_out','objetive','comments']].as_matrix()
```

Comment: thank u very much Julio. i try your code but this is the error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1229                 mask = check == -1
   1230                 if mask.any():
-> 1231                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1232 
   1233                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "[''id','date_in','date_out','objetive','comments''] not in index"

Comment: That means your columns have different names than those you specified. Can you post que result of `print(list(df))` just after loading the csv? That will tell you your column names